# Bushing OK or need clamp? NM-B 6/3 going into breaker box

Tags: electrical

I am adding a 14-50 outlet in the garage.  Running NM-B 6/3 Romex to existing breaker box. There is room for a 50AMP 240 breaker. I have 200A single phase service. Sheetrock above box.  I can drill a hole in the studs above the breaker box and feed wire into breaker box from attic. Because of the existing sheetrock I don't have access to put on a clamp with a nut on the top of the breaker box (without cutting sheetrock).  Can I use a simple bushing?  I think I need 3/4" or 1" bushing or clamp.  The electrician that helped me gave me a 1" bushing. Is that code?  I also see snap-in clamps.  That would work if I can find one. Do they make 3/4" snap-in clamps? Does code allow the simple nylon/plastic bushing where the wire enters the breaker box? What are my options?

Update: I used the NM95X as suggested in the replies to my question. Here is how it turned out. The 6/3 enters at the top center. I think I did a correct and pretty job. Critiques?[image]

Comment: Stop by an actual electrical supply house. They will be miffed that you bought everything at the box store and only bother with them when you need full service, but these are good people to create a relationship with and buy things from regularly.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I ordered an NM95X online. It should be here tomorrow. I won't  have to cut into the sheetrock. Thanks! Thanks! Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

### You'll need a 3/4" snap-in NM clamp that can be installed from the inside of the box

You do need a NM clamp (vs a mere bushing) here, first off; a simple bushing does not provide the clamping of the cable jacket required by NEC 312.5(C) for cabinets or 314.17(B)/(C) for boxes.  This NM clamp also needs to be installed from the *inside* of the cabinet, and that limits your options; in fact, the only product I know of offhand that fits the bill is the 3/4" [Arlington NM95X](http://www.aimedia.co/media/spec-sheets/NM94X.pdf), which maxes out precisely at 6/3.

Comment: Thanks for your help!    I see the electrical panel cover overlaps the sheetrock about 1/2". I guess I'll cut back the sheetrock just enough above the box to insert a nut. I can start the clamp into the nut.  Is that what would normally be done?

Comment: The Arlington NM95X snaps into the hole. No retainer nut is needed for this cable connector.

Comment: @Kent -- you don't need to mess with the sheetrock, as the Arlington NM95X can just be snapped into the knockout hole from the inside of the box

Comment: Thank you for your help! I ordered an NM95X online. It should be here tomorrow. I won't  have to cut into the sheetrock. Thanks! Thanks! Thanks!

Comment: @Kent we thank people around here by upvoting and/or accepting their answers :)

Comment: Done.  Thanks for mentioning the upvote. This is my first use of this website. I updated/edited the original question with how it turned out. I think it is looking good!

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid you do need a clamp.  There are clamps for smaller romex that install from inside the box, <strike>but I don't believe they are made for larger sizes like you need.</strike> and @ThreePhaseEel indicated in the comments there is a larger one available for 6/3 Romex

[Arlington NM95X](http://www.aifittings.com/catalog/non-metallic-cable-fittings-and-supports/white-button-non-metallic-push-in-connectors/NM95X) (see cables allowed below - your 6/3 is in there)

With these fittings, you fish the cable inside the wall into the box, then slide the fitting up the cable and snap the fitting into the knockout (hole).  You have to be careful the sharp edge of the knockout doesn't damage the cable jacket while until you get the fitting snapped in.

> Cable Ranges: One 14/2 to 6/2, **One 14/3 to 6/3**, One 12/4, One 12/2/2, Two 14/2 to 10/2, Two 14/3 to 10/3, One 14/2 and One 12/2, One 14/2 and One 10/2, One 12/2 and One 10/2, One 14/3 and One 12/3, One 14/2 NMB-PCS, One 12/2 NMB-PCS, One or Two 14/2 to 10/2 NMD90

Comment: While the Raco Insider only comes in 1/2", the Arlington White Button has a 3/4" version (Arlington NM95X)

Comment: Thank you for your help! I ordered an NM95X online. It should be here tomorrow. I won't  have to cut into the sheetrock. Thanks! Thanks! Thanks!